# Mirage for Testing and Firebase for devlopment - Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

In my application, I use firebase to store and retrieve data.

But for testing purpose i dont want data come from server, i need to mock the data using mirage and test that mock data.

In my adapter/application.js, i use firebase adapater

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import FirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/adapters/firebase';
const { inject } = Ember;
export default FirebaseAdapter.extend({
    firebase: inject.service(),
});
```

but in case of testing i want to use mirage, so my question where i want to change the adapter to mirage??? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your config/environment.js this should do it.

```
     if (environment === 'test') {
        // Testem prefers this...
        ENV.locationType = 'none';
        ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
            enabled: true
          }
        // keep test console output quieter
        ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
        ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

        ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
      }
```

I had something similar if you want to have your adapter different configuration import config environment in to your adapter and then use ENV.host or other variable that you need to set different  based on ENV in your case testing and development

```
     if (environment === 'test') {
        ENV.host = something


      }
     if (environment === 'development') {
        ENV.host = something else

      }
```

and your adapter example of active adapter change.

```
    import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';
    import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin'; 
    import config from '../config/environment';

    export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
      namespace: 'api',
      host: `${config.host}`,
      authorizer: 'authorizer:custom'
    });
```

I never used firebase so cant help you there but this is how you have different settings in your adapter based on ENV.

Comment: I have done this but still it sends request to firebase, i need to set `namesapce:'api'` to access mirage where i want to use this?

Comment: import config from '../config/environment';